# Salesforce: Create URL or custom link to master-detail object record list

Tags: salesforce

Goal: Remove a related list from the "Account" layout and place a custom link or URL field instead to redirect user to the record list as in the related list.

What I have now:
a Custom link with Behavior as "Execute Java Script".
OnClick JavaScript: window.open('https://xxxxxxxx.my.salesforce.com/a6F')

This link redirect user to all the records of this object they have access to.
But I need user to be redirected to records only related to this Account record.
Like to add a parameter in the URL like account__c = {current account ID}

Is this possible or any other workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could just have a look at what kind of link SF generates when you have a looong related list and there's a "Go to List" link. You'll see something like `/a6F?rlid=00N....&id=001...`

- `a6F` - you know that part already, it's the object's "keyPrefix" used to show tabs.
- `rlid` - ID of the lookup that links from your custom object up to Account. You can learn it by looking at URL displayed when you view this field in setup
- `id` - this (parent) Account's Id

Not all objects are linkable that way, for example Quote I think doesn't even have a Tab and you might get funny results with Tasks/Events... Custom objects should be fine though.

Alternatively consider making a report to which you pass a parameter at runtime. Search for "salesforce URL hacking"

Comment: Hi thank you it works. One more question is how can I customize the columns in the populated record list? Currently there's only 1 column of that Record ID.  Thank you!!!

Comment: Figured out! Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help!